# Organise Favourite Questions by Tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, bookmarks

I've been a SO member for awhile now and have amassed quite a few questions I have favourited for future reference. It would be nice if I could organise them in a manner other than the simple options available at present.

Possibly organising by tag or by some user defined criteria would be good.

Comment: I know it would be nicer as a built-in feature but I've made a userscript to let you 'tag' favourites at stackapps: [Favourites Enhancer: Tag favourites and add personal notes](https://stackapps.com/q/6215) (also on the other meta post :)